What is an angle?
I am a high school student and recently I started trigonometry and one question that comes to my mind every time is that "What is an angle?"
I mean when we say that angle between two sides of a triangle is theta, what does it measure?
Is there any definition of angle or is it just conventionally defined like a point or a line?
